# Scale sprite according rotation. How to calculate it correctly for my situation? [Math-iphone-cocos2d]

Tags: iphone, math, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, scale

At first:
I'm using cocos2d for iphone. But this isn't so important for this question.

My problem is now...I want to scale a sprite on the Y axis. I can do that with this function:

```
mySprite.scaleY = myFloatValue;
```

I want to set the scaleY value related to the rotation of the sprite..

Some cases:

If the rotation is 0, scaleY is 0.
If the rotation is 90, scaleY is 1.
If the rotation is 180 scaleY is 0
If the rotation is 360 scaleY is 0.
If the rotation is 45 scaleY is 0.5.

Some more explanation:
If my sprite is vertical the scaleY value is 1.
If my sprite is horizontal the scaleY value is 0.

And I need a forumula for this.

I got it working for the angles between 0 and 90:

mySprite.scaleY = rotation/90.0f;

From the angles between 90 and 180 teh scaleY should go from 1.0 to 0.0f

I want to make a smooth scaling..

Btw, did you understood what I want? If not I could make a video or some screenshots..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `mySprite.scaleY = sinf(rotation);`

EDIT:

To make it always positive

```
mySprite.scaleY = fabs(sinf(rotation));
```

Where rotation is in ***radians***

```
mySprite.scaleY = fabs(sinf(M_PI * rotation / 180));
```

Where rotation is in ***degrees***

Comment: what exactly does this do? Could you make a example for 45?

Comment: this will only give me 0 or 1 or -1 value but I need a forumla which can calculate it for every value such as 0.02f and soon on...a general formula

Comment: The sin of a value between 0 and 2 * PI (0 to 360 degrees) varies continuously from 0 to 1 to 0 to -1 and back to 0, so I am not sure what you don't understand.  If you always want to make it positive use fabs(sinf(rotation))

Comment: but for the rotation 45 I need the scaleY to be 0.5f. It needs to be more precise..for every value between 0 and 360 degrees. Decimal values too. for 1,1.1,1.2,1.3 and so on...I need more accurate float values.

Comment: Have you tried this at all?  fabs(sinf(M_PI * 45 / 180)) = 0.5f.  I think you are not converting to radians first.

Comment: It works. Thank you...I accepted your answer. Could you explain me the code please? I didn't really understood it completely. You'll get a +1 of course ;)

Comment: From trigonometry the sine of an angle is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine and produces a wave that oscillates between 1 and -1 (see picture in the article).  Angles can be measured in degrees (a full circle having 360 degrees) or radians (a full circle having 2 * PI radians).  Most trigonometry functions in C use radians rather than degrees so you usually convert first by radians = 2 * PI / 360 degrees, which simplifies to radians = PI / 180 degrees.  The fabs function simply removes the sign from a value so -1 becomes 1 for instance.  HTH Dave.